# Filter out decimal value in transform message in mule

Tags: json, dataweave, mule-esb

I have an json payload where I need to filter out decimal value 0.00 by using filter in transform message.
Please find the transform message:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java

---
payload map ((currentOptyLineItem , currentOptyLineItemIndex) -> {
    OpportunityId: currentOptyLineItem.OPPORTUNITYID,
    PricebookEntryId: currentOptyLineItem.PRICEBOOKENTRYID,
    Mix__c: currentOptyLineItem.MIX__C ,
    Product_Family__c: currentOptyLineItem.PRODUCT_FAMILY__C,
    QuoteId__c: currentOptyLineItem.QUOTEID__C as :string,
    Extended_Net_Price__c: currentOptyLineItem.EXTENDED_NET_PRICE__C,
    Recurring_Percentage__c: currentOptyLineItem.RECURRING_PERCENTAGE,
    Term__c : currentOptyLineItem.TERM,
    Product_Family_Service_Level_Recurring__c: currentOptyLineItem.ROFLAG,
    Product_with_Product_Family__c : currentOptyLineItem.BUSINESS_ENTITY__C as :string ++ "-" ++ currentOptyLineItem.SUB_BUSINESS_ENTITY__C as :string ++ "-" ++ currentOptyLineItem.PRODUCT_FAMILY__C
} filter currentOptyLineItem.MIX__C > 0
)
```

but I get error message as:

> Root Exception stack trace:
>   com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException: Exception
>   while executing:  payload.Product_with_Product_Family__c map
>   ((referenceKey ,  index) -> "'" ++ referenceKey ++ "'") reduce ($$ ++
>   "," ++ $) ^ Type mismatch for 'map' operator
>        found :null, :function   required :array, :function.

Comment: Including a sample payload would be most helpful.

Comment: Please fine the sample payload:

Comment: {
      "name": "xxx",
      "beInfo": [
        {
          "name": "Collaboration",
          "subBeInfo": [
            {
              "name": "yyy",
              "roDetails": [
                {
                  "roFlag": "N",
                  "termInfo": [{
                      "extNetPrice": 95398.85, "term": 12
                    }]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },

Comment: Hi, Two things the input you specify doesn't match your script, neither the error.
Now based on the error message looks like there is an expression 
`payload.Product_with_Product_Family__c map ...` somewhere on your mule code and the Product_withProduct_Family__c is null
You can easily fix this by using `payload.Product_with_Product_Family__c default [] map ...`

Comment: As mentioned in the above post please, furnish the right input payload. Although you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this if you want it without decimals:

```
Extended_Net_Price__c: currentOptyLineItem.EXTENDED_NET_PRICE__C as :string {format: "#.#####"}
```

otherwise for number of decimal place it can be achieved as:

```
Extended_Net_Price__c: currentOptyLineItem.EXTENDED_NET_PRICE__C as :number {format: '#.#####'}
```

Comment: I need to filter this field  Mix__c: currentOptyLineItem.MIX__C  as it receives 0.00 % from the payload... So can you please let me how to use this filter option in the transform message.